# Representing data as a string

Tags: haskell

I have the following simple code:

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float deriving (Show)
surface :: Shape -> Float
surface (Circle _ _ r) = pi * r ^ 2

main = putStrLn $ surface $ Circle 10 20 30
```

It complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `Float'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `surface $ Circle 10 20 30'
```

How do I get rid of the error? I also would like to "add" `show` method to `Shape` and override it so that I can represent `Shape` on the screen (printed) whatever I want.

Comment: BTW you should better use record syntax here, e.g. `Circle { circleX , circleY , circleRadius :: Float }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add show:

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ surface $ Circle 10 20 30
```

If you want your own Show method, don't derive Show:

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float
           | Rectangle Float Float Float Float

instance Show Shape where   
  show (Circle _ _ r) = show r   
  show (Rectangle r _ _ _) = show r

main = putStrLn $ show $ Circle 10 20 30
```

Comment: how do I apply show to many arguments like here: `show (Circle _ _ r) = show $ "test123" r`

Comment: show is just like any other function.  I'm not sure exactly what you wanted to do, but if concatenation is what you want, you'd do show (Circle _ _ r) = "test123" ++ show r